# How to check whether clicked li element has specific class

Tags: jquery

I have multiple list items in that when i click on perticular li i want to check the li on which i have clicked has any specific class or not the code which i have written it is not working so how to check this?

```js
$(".sub-menu li").on('click', function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('matter')) {
    alert();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li class="matter">list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
  <li>list 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Putting your exact code in a snippet and including jQuery, it appears to work.

Comment: Your example is working. You might have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: have you checked your browser's console for errors?